# Finding the middle object of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with this python 3 exercise, to find the median of a list. you're supposed to define and make your own function, and that's what i did.

EXERCISE:

> Write a function `middle(L)` which takes a list `L` as its argument, and returns the item in the middle position of `L`. (In order that the middle is well-defined, you should assume that `L` has odd length.) For example, calling `middle([8, 0, 100, 12, 1])` should return `100`, since it is positioned exactly in the middle of the list.

Here is my code:

```
def middle(a):
    a = sorted(a)
    l = len(a)

    if len(a) % 2 == 0.:
        m = (a[int(l / 2)] + a[int(l / 2) - 1]) / 2.
    else:
        if l < 2:
            m = a[0]
        else:
            m = a[int(l / 2)]

    return m
```

when I tried this in another site, it worked. But I get the following error when I put it in this site:

> Program executed without crashing.
>       The grader said:
>       Running middle([8, 0, 100, 12, 1]) … Error: middle([8, 0, 100, 12, 1]) has wrong value 8, expected 100

The argument name being `a` instead of `L` has nothing to do with the wrong answer as I already tried changing it to `L`.

**update**

THANK YOU FOR THE HELP. IT WORKED WHEN i REMOVED THE `A = SORTED(A)` CHUNK.

Comment: It *works*, as in it's valid code that runs, but it's *wrong*, as in you don't appear to have **actually read the exercise**. Where in the specification does it mention sorting?

Comment: Your code does not solve exercise at all. You should throw away your solution, **read** exercise once more, and write new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you misread the assignment and wrote a function to return the *median*, while the question was to return the *middle*. If you remove the `a=sorted(a)` it should work.

Comment: oh ok.. i misread that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read the assignment. You only need to return the item in the middle of the list. No sorting, no median. And you can assume that the list always have a odd length.

```
def middle(L):
    return L[len(L) // 2]
```